# sharePoint 2013 - IE10 detects extra body tag

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am seeing the following messsage in the console window for IE10...

```
Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.
```

But when I open my master template I don't see an additional body tag element...but I do see that sharepoint trying to load the following HTML element before the `<head>` element...

```
<span id="DeltaSPWebPartManager">

</span>
```

Any advice in removing this warning will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found the culprit. Just move that tag into the body section and it should eliminate that extra body warning. If you're editing the .html version of the master page make sure to move the whole snippet:

```
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">-->
        <!--MS:<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

It will cause other problems if you leave it in the head section. Randy Drisgill talks about it here: http://blog.drisgill.com/2013/04/starter-master-pages-update-v1-3.html